# OpenLayers 5 | Angular 7 | Angular Material | Map is not working inside angular material mat-stepper

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, openlayers, angular7

I have imported OpenLayers map in my component ts file, then I have created a div block with id = map where must be displayed the OpenLayers map, but it does not. When I moved the div block (#map) outside of mat-stepper blocks, then it works.

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import OlMap from 'ol/Map';
import OlXYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import OlTileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OlView from 'ol/View';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sell',
  templateUrl: './sell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sell.component.scss'],
})
export class SellComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  map: OlMap;
  source: OlXYZ;
  layer: OlTileLayer;
  view: OlView;

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.source = new OlXYZ({
      url: 'http://tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    });

    this.layer = new OlTileLayer({
      source: this.source,
    });

    this.view = new OlView({
      center: fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
      zoom: 3,
    });

    this.map = new OlMap({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [this.layer],
      view: this.view,
    });
  }
```

Component.html:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper
  linear
  labelPosition="bottom"
  #stepper
  class="sell-form-container"
>
  <mat-step ...>
    <form ...>
      ...
      <div id="map"></div>  //<- here it does not work, map does not display
      ...
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  ...
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
<div id="map"></div> //<- here it works, map displays
```

Component.css:

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is related to the content you're trying to attach the OLMap to being in the transcluded content of the mat-stepper or mat-step.

In the component lifecycle, the child component is not ready at the parent's OnInit step. Because you put the div you need inside of the mat component, it is being included in that component lifecycle instead.

One way you should be able to solve this is by working with the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle method. Having your code in that method should solve this issue.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.map = new OlMap({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [this.layer],
    view: this.view,
  });
}
```

---

I'd like to present another way to work with components as well for the sake of potential curiosity. Keeping an eye on transcluded content, if the element you want is in the current component, you should use the ViewChild decorator to select it. Otherwise if it is in a child component, use the ContentChild decorator.

```
// html
<mat-horizontal-stepper ...>
  <mat-step ...>
    <form ...>
      ...
      <div #myMapRef id="map"></div>
      ...
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  ...
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

// parent ts
@ContentChild('myMapRef') // <-- if it's in a child component, your case should use this
@ViewChild('myMapRef') // <-- if it's in this component, your "this is working" would use this
myMap: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.myMap); // can get the ID from the ElementRef
}
```

I highly recommend actually getting familiar with the depths of the component lifecycle. This is one thing I wish I did earlier on while learning Angular.

- [Angular Lifecycle Methods](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)
- [Angular ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild)
- [Angular ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)
- [A long example blog post](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/)
- [After Content Example](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#aftercontent)
- [After View Example](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview)